# PDFLIB How to cancel the '-' in TextFlow

Tags: pdflib

[enter image description here][1]
I want to cancel the '-' in this textflow and at the same time Multiple lines show.
(i know "avoidwordsplitting" but it is single line show)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygrtq.png

Comment: Here's the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygrtq.png

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? You are placing a string into a textflow that is too long for a single line, so it has to be split. Do you want the string to be split automatically, but without hyphens?

Comment: thank you,i have find the answer.use option --"hyphenchar=none"